# How to get PHAsset defaultRepresentation using Photos.framework in Obj-C. AssetsLibrary.framework is deprecated since iOS9

Tags: objective-c, ios9

How to get PHAsset defaultRepresentation using Photos.framework in Obj-C. AssetsLibrary.framework is deprecated since iOS9.

```
//Returns an ALAssetRepresentation object for the default representation of the ALAsset
- (ALAssetRepresentation *)defaultRepresentation NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(4_0, 9_0, "Use PHImageRequestOptions with the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead");
```

**example of AssetsLibrary.framework**

```
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *asset) {
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
CGImageRef iref = [rep fullScreenImage];

/*
//Commented Section of Code
*/
}
ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock = ^(NSError *error)
{
/*
//Commented Section of Code
*/            
};
ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
[assetsLib assetForURL:url resultBlock:resultblock  failureBlock:failureblock];
```

We have to use PHImageRequestOptions with the PHImageManager from the Photos framework to get [asset defaultRepresentation].How ?

Earlier we were using ALAssetRepresentation which was good for before iOS9.

Answer (score 2):

PHAsset is much interesting.

You can get image object from the asset is bit similar to ALAsset.

You can do it using below code.

```
PHAsset *asset = _assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item];

[_imageManager requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:nil resultHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable imageData, NSString * _Nullable dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
        UIImage *tempImageFromData = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}];
```

Happy Coding...

Where `_imageManager` is instance of `PHCachingImageManager`

Comment: It will be great if you may help me to know the following. I have to achieve the same using Photos.framework. ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];

Comment: I have to access defaultRepresentation property using Photos.framework. It was part of AssetsLibrary.framework.

Comment: In Photos.framework i think nothing like defaultRepresentation property. I had spent many time and after i reach to the above solution. Above mentioned code is the way to get all kind of details of the assets. Please go ahead with the same. completion handler will not come in your way.

Comment: Thanks @Chetan. It helps.